# How to represent the relative geometry of two ellipses with a common focus in GeoGebra?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, rotations

I'm studying an astrodynamics problem and to help my study I'd like to represent the geometry I'm dealing with. I also obtained a figure in Matlab but I need to represent many angles and so I'd like to avoid to write too lines of code.

My objective is to represent two ellipses, (ell1 and ell2) with a common focus, in the perifocal reference frame of ell1 and this is the main problem that I have, beacuse in the cartesian coordinates of GeoGebra I am able to write the equation of ell1 as (x/a1)^2 + (y/b1)^2 = 1 but I'm having trouble correctly writing the cartesian equation of ell2; it should be something like (x-x0/a2)^2 + (y/b2)^2 = 1. Of course the focus is the same for both ellipses, let's assume F(c,0). In addition, I want to represent the second ellipse rotated of an angle equal to 120 deg about the focus wrt the first ellipse and their intersection point.

The data that I have are semimajor axes, eccentricities and the difference of the arguments of periapsides:
a1 = 154448562.453878 km
e1 = 0.0524440272062934
a2 = 143768968.725253 km
e2 = 0.027842283175748
delta_omega = 120 deg

The data listed above correspond to a tangency condition between two ellipses shown in Matlab figure. It would be amazing to be able to represent in GeoGebra the ell1 fixed and the ell2 rotating and contemporary showing the intersection points (one or two depending on the relative geometry), hence to start with their apsides lines overlapped and then rotate the second one wrt the first one.

Here is the matlab figure that I would like to get:
[image: relative geometry]

Here is the scheme I've obtainend up to now in GeoGebra:
[GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/m/pjae8z6u)

My questions are:

- Is it possible to use a perifocal reference frame in GeoGebra or do I have to use the cartesian one?
- Can you help me to draw the problem described above?

Comment: For GeoGebra [this](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Rotate_Command) might be useful.

Comment: Thank you @JohnWaylandBales but the first problem to solve is the representation of the ellipse2 that has the focus in common with ellipse1.

Comment: Why should you use an equation? You can just construct the second focus of the second ellipse (using the data you have) and the periastron, then use the Ellipse tool.

Comment: Thank you @Intelligentipauca. Can you explain better your solution?
The focus is the same for both ellipses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see below those two ellipses, drawn with GeoGebra. Here's the construction, step by step.

1. Use the Point tool to set point F (the common focus) at the origin.
2. Input `a1 = 1.54449...`, `a2 = 1.43769...`, `e1 = 0.05244...`, `e2 = 0.02784...` in the command bar.
3. Input `F1=(-2*a1*e1,0)` to find the focus of the first ellipse.
4. Input `A1=(a1*(1-e1),0)` to find the periastron of the first ellipse.
5. Use the Ellipse tool to draw the first ellipse (red).
6. Input `u2=Rotate[(1,0),120°]` to create a unit vector towards the periastron of the second ellipse.
7. Input `F2=-2*a2*e2*u2` to find the focus of the second ellipse.
8. Input `A2=a2*(1-e2)*u2` to find the periastron of the second ellipse.
9. Use the Ellipse tool to draw the second ellipse (blue).

I then used the Intersect tool to find the intersections between the ellipses (points P and Q).

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm following your procedure but I'm having trouble in finding intersection, ii seems that there is no intersection. Can you take a look at my project, please?
https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/qp85c9cq

Comment: @Giuseppe I cannot access your GeoGebra file ("Opening file failed"). I suspect it could be a problem of accuracy: try the construction with the off-line app (download GeoGebra Classic). And of course you must input the constants with all the given digits.

Comment: @Giuseppe It is not a problem of accuracy of the online version: I've just done the construction with GeoGebra Classic online and it works. You can see it here: https://www.geogebra.org/classic/mr4qer4s

Comment: Try now: https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/qp85c9cq

However I see that you used less decimal digits. Can be this fact the reason for why in my case it is not possible to find intersections?
P.s. I used GeoGebra Calulator Suite.

Comment: @Giuseppe I input those numbers exactly as you wrote them in your question. Of course changing them a bit can affect the result. Looks like [GeoGebra works to a maximum of 15 significant digits](https://help.geogebra.org/topic/decimal-precision-question).

Comment: @Giuseppe I'm afraid "GeoGebra Calculator" cannot compute the intersections of two ellipses: try with GeoGebra Classic.

Comment: Hi @Intelligenti pauca, I understood why with my numbers it was not possible to find intersections: It is probably due to the fact that the solver has difficulties to work with large numbers and so I used astronomical unit, so I understand why you use small points instead of km in your example.
One last question: Why do you rotate around the point(1,0) to get the unit vector u2?

Comment: @Giuseppe The `Rotate[(1,0),120°]` command rotates vector (1,0) about **the origin** by 120°. If you want to rotate about some other centre C, instead of the origin, just use `Rotate[(1,0),120°,C]`. See here: https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Rotate_Command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136219/discussion-between-giuseppe-and-intelligenti-pauca).